# VBA Macro to auto browse and open a file

Tags: vba, excel, automation, macros

I am writing a VBA macro to fill a web form with values from spreadsheet.

I have completed macro to fill all form fields except one to click on a button in form to `Browse for files`.

Below is the macro line to click the browse button.
`IE.Document.getElementById("notification_picture").Click`

I'm clueless on how to do the next steps i.e. to browse to a particular folder, select and open the file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Man... particularly deal with IE is a pain...

You could use

```
Sendkeys "%S"
```

It will save it in Downloads folder and then you can move it, open or do whatever you want.

Many will say it is not good to use it because if the user change the focus while the macro is running it will not working, but it is the simplest way.